# TFS Build hiding custom assemblies in build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have my custom continous build that log an error for my tfs service host.

> Service 'Default Agent - basv-tfs-001' had an exception:  Exception
>   Message: Problem with loading custom assemblies: API restriction: The
>   assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\ProjectBranchDevelopment\BuildAgent\2\ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll'
>   has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from
>   a new location within the same appdomain. (type Exception)

I have found i have the same dll saved in 2 locations in my repository.
can i hide it from build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the workspace in your build definition. Add a reference to the folder containing one of the dll's and change "active" to "cloaked" that will stop TFS getting that folder during the build

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in tests where it's defaulted to using ***test*.dll (or similar), to get round this I changed it to just *test*.dll, since it was (as the error suggests) finding it in multiple locations.

So whatever is attempting to resolve your DLL is probably doing something similar.  Not a solution I know by may help you track down the offending code :)